# How to change the height of sub-menubar in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-menu

By using sub-menu bar I am taking text size as input and based that input I'm gonna change the font size in text_area. But the problem is with the huge of size sub-menu bar. Is there any way to resize it's height?

For more clarity on the problem please refer the below image,

[sub-menubar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP91u.jpg)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Notepad")
root.geometry("900x570+270+30")
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text_area = Text(root, bg="azure2", fg="Black", yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
text_area.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

# Creating top level menubar
menubar = Menu(root)

def font_size(size):
    # I'm doing some stuff with the size
    pass

viewmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
viewmenu.add_command(label="fg color", command="")
viewmenu.add_command(label="bg color", command="")

font_submenu = Menu(viewmenu,tearoff=0)

# Problem: Below 'for' loop creating huge height sub menubar
for size in range(2, 86, 2):
   font_submenu.add_command(label=str(size), command=font_size(size))

viewmenu.add_cascade(label="Font", menu=font_submenu, underline=1)
menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=viewmenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: From a usability point of view, you should avoid making such huge menus.

Comment: Maybe you could consider to use `add_command` and make a `Entry` to let user input the number.

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley and @jizhihaoSAMA for your valuable suggestions. Yes, if I'm not able to find solution for this issue, I will definitely go for `Entry` option.